# VisualForce page, PDF, styling list items

Tags: visualforce, list, pdf

Normally, using CSS it is possible to add a white space between the bullet or number and the text behind it.

```
<ul>
  <li style="padding-left: 10px;">Text entry</li>
  <li style="padding-left: 20px;">Text entry</li>
  <li style="padding-left: 30px;">Text entry</li>
  <li style="padding-left: 40px;">Text entry</li>
</ul>
```

But in the PDF it is Shown as if it was written as:

```
<ul>
  <li style="margin-left: 10px;">Text entry</li>
  <li style="margin-left: 20px;">Text entry</li>
  <li style="margin-left: 30px;">Text entry</li>
  <li style="margin-left: 40px;">Text entry</li>
</ul>
```

Any idea how to achieve this functionality?

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yap1txvz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the styling is quite strict on `renderAs="pdf"`.

Not sure why the behavior is different in PDF, UI can be achieved by having a span inside list item and style the span.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span style="padding-left: 10px;">
            Text entry
        </span>
    </li>
  <li>
        <span style="padding-left: 20px;">
            Text entry
        </span>
    </li>
  <li>
        <span style="padding-left: 30px;">
            Text entry
        </span>
    </li>
  <li>
        <span style="padding-left: 40px;">
            Text entry
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: Smart, but ugly. But it will do! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Its not ugly but also schematically correct in [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904843/what-child-elements-are-valid-inside-of-a-li/17904868). Cheers! :)

Comment: True, it is correct in HTML. But it would have been nice if it was possible using CSS.
Additional note, you can make the span display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; to indent the entire text as block.